# Laptop HDD problems caused by moving the laptop

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

well last week I took my laptop (it was on and I forgot to turn it off) to a trip. after I got there, it was turned off, I tried turning it on but no HDD was detected, I tried 3 or 4 times and it was finally detected. the problem is every time I turn it off it won't detect the HDD the next time it is turned on, but when it's detected there is no problem, I used different diagnosis tools but none reported a single problem with my HDD. I've been told that laptop hards remove the header from the disk when they are turned off and my problem maybe because of the header somehow sticks and it caused by the long trip and etc. I want to know if there is a solution for this cause the hard works fine when it is detected. the laptop also makes a "tic toc" sound when it's turned on and can not detect the HDD.
my laptop is lenovo z580 Ideapad
OS windows 7 Ultimate
regards

Answer (score 1):

The solution is - definitely - to replace the hard drive in the laptop.  If you have the equipment to do it, you can remove the drive from the laptop and from the sounds of it you can do a bit copy to the new drive and simply pop it in.  (The equipment required is either a PC which you can put the 2 hard drives in, or a hard drive enclosure or equivalent which you can temporarily put the internal drive in.

Its important to realize that your harddrive is stuffed and living on borrowed time.  You should back it up and replace it ASAP.

Comment: I have 2 backups from that hard, but what you mean is my hard drive is broken for sure? you mean the reports from all diagnosis tools are not correct and I should get a new hard?

Comment: You know one thing for sure: The part that is holding all your precious data is acting unreliably. If you want to "salvage" it, get an external enclosure and make some use of the old one after replacing it. But i agree with david, replace ASAP, even though it MIGHT MAYBE not be fully broken. It might also just be a hint from fate to buy an SSD btw. and thereby giving the laptop a boost. :-)

Comment: OK ty both david and @TheUser1024, I think you might be right I would probably get a ssd and use this drive as the secondary storage hard. tnx for your time.